# PL SQL Package Getting ORA-0900

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL SQL and I wrote a validation package for our company's Banner program and I cant seem to catch what is invalid.  I have updated the variable but it is still showing invalid, I put in fake tables to see if it would give me the same error but it did not.  When I am running it like a package it will not tell me where the error is only that it is invalid.

```
 create or replace package NMGC_CAABTRN_DB is

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                            --
-- COPYRIGHT 2023 -  Hansen Technologies  - ALL RIGHTS RESERVED               --
--                                                                            --
-- DESCRIPTION:    Support procedures for CUSTOMER CLASS VALIDATION (CAABTRN)  --
--                                                                            --
/**************************************************************************

!@#$%^&*() AUDIT START !@#$%^&*()

   AUDIT TRAIL                                             INIT     DATE
   ------------------------------------------------------  ----- ------------
   Release: 2023_NMGC
   ~!@B2021_NMGC
   1.                                      PP    08/22/2023
      Initial Version. Support procedures for Account Customer Validation (CAABTRN)
                 

!@#$% AUDIT END !@#$%
**************************************************************************/

   FUNCTION version RETURN VARCHAR2; -- PATRICK NOTE Boilerplate, leave in

  --PATRICK NOTE input parameters are boilerplate and must remain as is
   PROCEDURE validateCustomerClass (p_action            IN VARCHAR2,
                                 p_data              IN CLOB,
                                 p_languageCode      IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'ENG',
                                 p_statusInd         OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 p_messageJSON       OUT CLOB,
                                 p_returnFieldsJSON  OUT CLOB );      

END NMGC_CAABTRN_DB;

    -- Author  : AAPWP
  -- Created : 9/6/2023 8:19:21 AM
  -- Purpose : Prevent C to R cash transfer
  
   procedureName            CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'NMGC_CAABTRN_DB';
   currentRelease           CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := '2021_NMGC';
   devVersion               CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := '001';
   g_nullChar               CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1)  := NULL;
   g_dateFormatWithTime     CONSTANT VARCHAR2(16) := RULE_DB.systemRulesValue('DATE_FORMAT');
   stopProcessing           EXCEPTION;
   
   /*PATRICK NOTE Create and set variables to retrieve values from the property set member keys on the screen using the example below.
    The type for all must be what is here - the only thing that changes are the names and the value between '' (MUST MATCH VALUE OF PROPERTY SET MEMBER KEY!)*/
   PREM_CODE_FROM     CONSTANT PROPERTY.PROPERTYKEY%TYPE := 'PREM_CODE_FROM'; 
   PREM_CODE_TO       CONSTANT PROPERTY.PROPERTYKEY%TYPE := 'PREM_CODE_TO';
   
   




  
   ------------------------------
   -- private functions/procedure
   ------------------------------
   --PATRICK NOTE Start of boilerplate procedures - LEAVE AS IS
   PROCEDURE logMessage (errorObject   IN VARCHAR2,
                         errorMessage  IN U$_DL_Data_Types_Db.ErrorCode_Type,
                         errorPriority IN NUMBER DEFAULT 10 ) IS
      logMessageFlag                VARCHAR2(4)  := SYS_CONTEXT('CS_GLB_CTX', procedureName);
      logMessageCapacity            NUMBER := 4000;
   BEGIN
      -- procedureName is actually Package Name.
      -- errorObject is the Method Name.
      -- errorMessage is the Message we want to log.
      -- Debug logging in local mode
      BEGIN
         IF logMessageFlag IS NULL OR (SUBSTR(logMessageFlag, 1, 1) = 'Y' AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(logMessageFlag, 2)) <= errorPriority) THEN
            U$_LOGM.ADD_ENTRY(procedureName, substr(to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF9')|| ' ' || errorObject || ' : ' || errorMessage, 1, logMessageCapacity), errorPriority);
         END IF;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
      END;
      -- Debug logging in the global mode
      BEGIN
         U$_PL_USTDEBG_DB.P_LOG_MESSAGE(TO_CLOB(errorMessage), 'PACKAGE BODY', procedureName, errorObject);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
      END;
   END logMessage;



   ------------------------------
   -- public functions/procedure
   ------------------------------
   FUNCTION version RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN MISC_DB.formatVersion(procedureName, currentRelease, devVersion);
   END version;
   --PATRICK NOTE END of boilerplate
   
   --PATRICK NOTE Rename your procedure to describe what you're doing using the same camel case convention - leave parameters as is
   PROCEDURE validateCustomerClass (p_action            IN VARCHAR2,   -- values 'I','U','D', 'S'
                                    p_data              IN CLOB,       -- JSON format
                                    p_languageCode      IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'ENG',
                                    p_statusInd         OUT VARCHAR2,  -- 'P' or 'F'
                                    p_messageJSON       OUT CLOB,      -- JSON format
                                    p_returnFieldsJSON  OUT CLOB ) AS

      --PATRICK NOTE boilerplate variables
    -- processMessage variables
      d_messageRec            U$_OL_Messages_DB.applicationMessage_Record_Type;
      d_msgTypeErrorExists    BOOLEAN := FALSE;
      d_languageCode          VARCHAR2(10) := NVL(p_languageCode, 'ENG');

      -- validation variables
      d_propertyKey     VARCHAR2(30);
      missingColData    EXCEPTION;
      columnDataError   EXCEPTION;
      d_tableIndex      BINARY_INTEGER;
      d_psKey           VARCHAR2(30);
      d_rowID           VARCHAR2(30);
      return_Ind        VARCHAR2(255);
    
    --PATRICK NOTE set your variables here following the below convention. Try to use the column typing from the table to set the variable type
      d_STYP_CODE      UCRSERV.UCRSERV_STYP_CODE%TYPE;
      
      --PATRICK NOTE cursors are used if you need to run a query in your validation method to look up data
      CURSOR Customer_Class_Code (c_stypCode UCRSERV.UCRSERV_STYP_CODE%TYPE) IS
             SELECT 'X'
             FROM UCRSERV
             WHERE UCRSERV_STYP_code = d_STYP_CODE;
             
  --PATRICK NOTE boilerplate begin
   BEGIN
      p_statusInd := 'P';

      IF U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.calledFromProcessDML THEN
         d_tableIndex := U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.currentTableIndex;
      ELSE
         d_tableIndex := U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.buildtableRows(p_data);
      END IF;

      d_rowid := U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.tableRow(d_tableIndex).tableRowid;
      d_psKey := U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.tableRow(d_tableIndex).propertySetKey;
      
      --PATRICK NOTE boilerplate end
      -- retrieve column values from array
    
      BEGIN -- --PATRICK NOTE this section retrieves values from your screen into the procedure variables
         IF p_action != 'S' THEN ----PATRICK NOTE bp, S is search
           d_propertyKey := UCRSERV_STYPE_CODE; ----PATRICK NOTE this sets the property set member to be evaluated
           IF U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.tableRow(d_tableIndex).propertyKey.EXISTS(d_propertyKey) THEN --PATRICK NOTE verify if the key exists 
              d_STYP_CODE := U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.tableRow(d_tableIndex).propertyKey(d_propertyKey).value; --PATRICK NOTE if so retrieve value into local variable
           ELSE
              d_STYP_CODE := NULL;
           END IF;
     --PATRICK NOTE repeat for every property key you need to retrieve values for
         IF p_action != 'S' THEN ----PATRICK NOTE bp, S is search
           d_propertyKey := PREM_CODE_TO; ----PATRICK NOTE this sets the property set member to be evaluated
           IF U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.tableRow(d_tableIndex).propertyKey.EXISTS(d_propertyKey) THEN --PATRICK NOTE verify if the key exists 
              d_STYP_CODE := U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.tableRow(d_tableIndex).propertyKey(d_propertyKey).value; --PATRICK NOTE if so retrieve value into local variable
           ELSE
              d_STYP_CODE := NULL;
         END IF;
  --PATRICK NOTE bp exception
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RAISE missingColData;
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE columnDataError;
      END;
  --PATRICK NOTE bp end - the following section begins the actual validation
      IF p_action = 'S' THEN --PATRICK NOTE this would be if you want to place a validation on the search
         d_propertyKey := UZVTRFF_CODE_KEY;
         IF U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.tableRow(d_tableIndex).propertyKey.EXISTS(d_propertyKey) THEN
              d_STYPE_CODE := U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.tableRow(d_tableIndex).propertyKey(d_propertyKey).value;
         END IF;
    
    --PATRICK NOTE this section gets fired off on Insert/Update/Delete
      ELSE -- Action Type I, U, D
    --PATRICK NOTE set the property key for the member you want the validation to show the error on
         d_propertyKey := UZVTRFF_CODE_KEY;
     --PATRICK NOTE always good to check if the variable is not null to begin
         IF d_STYPE_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN
            OPEN Customer_Class_Code(d_STYPE_CODE);
            FETCH Customer_Class_Code_Cursor INTO return_Ind;
            IF Customer_Class_Code_Cursor%FOUND THEN
              -- STYP code is already defined
        --PATRICK NOTE this is a support procedure to retrieve a message from the UGOTMESG table and show on the field, the 1st parm is the message_id from that table
        -- and the rest is bp parameters
              U$_OL_Messages_DB.processMessage('PNM-0251', d_messageRec, d_msgTypeErrorExists, d_languageCode, d_propertyKey);
            END IF;
      CLOSE Tariff_Code_Cursor;
         END IF;
     --PATRICK NOTE repeat above block for all validations required
      END IF;
  
  --PATRICK NOTE ALL boilerplate from here to END
      -- set the return JSONs and status
      U$_OL_Messages_DB.getMessageJSON(p_messageJSON);
      U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.getReturnFieldsJSON(p_returnFieldsJSON);
      IF d_msgTypeErrorExists THEN
         p_statusInd := 'F';
      END IF;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN missingColData THEN
         p_statusInd := 'F';
         -- No data found for <P1>
         U$_OL_Messages_DB.processMessage('CIS-4810', d_messageRec, d_msgTypeErrorExists, d_languageCode, d_propertyKey, d_propertyKey);
         U$_OL_Messages_DB.getMessageJSON(p_messageJSON);
         U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.getReturnFieldsJSON(p_returnFieldsJSON);
         logMessage('validateCustomerClass', 'No data found for ' || d_propertyKey);
      WHEN columnDataError THEN
         p_statusInd := 'F';
         -- Data error for <P1>
         U$_OL_Messages_DB.processMessage('CIS-4811', d_messageRec, d_msgTypeErrorExists, d_languageCode, d_propertyKey, d_propertyKey);
         U$_OL_Messages_DB.getMessageJSON(p_messageJSON);
         U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.getReturnFieldsJSON(p_returnFieldsJSON);
         logMessage('validateCustomerClass', 'Data error for ' || d_propertyKey);
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         p_statusInd := 'F';
         -- Database error: <P1>
         U$_OL_Messages_DB.processMessage('CIS-4800', d_messageRec, d_msgTypeErrorExists, d_languageCode, d_propertyKey, SQLERRM);
         U$_OL_Messages_DB.getMessageJSON(p_messageJSON);
         U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.getReturnFieldsJSON(p_returnFieldsJSON);
        logMessage('validateCustomerClass', SQLERRM);
   END validateCustomerClass;
   --PATRICK NOTE EACH property set member(screen field) requiring validation needs its own procedure so copy and paste from PROCEDURE to END
   --and customize for the field - DON'T FORGET to put it in on the spec side as well
END NMGC_CAABTRN_DB;
/
```

Comment: After compiling the package (and its failure), run `select * From user_errors where name = 'NMGC_CAABTRN_DB';` to see what's wrong.

Comment: Use a gui tool like sql developer to write your pl/sql objects. It's going to save you a ton of time

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a statement terminator (a slash `/` on a new line after the `END` statement):

```sql
create or replace package NMGC_CAABTRN_DB is
  -- package signatures
END NMGC_CAABTRN_DB;
/
```

Then you are missing the `CREATE PACKAGE BODY` statement:

```sql
create or replace package body NMGC_CAABTRN_DB is
```

Then on about line 130 of the package body, you have various `IF ... END IF;` statements then an `EXCEPTION` statement and the number of preceding `END IF`s does not match the number of `IF`s so the `EXCEPTION` is raising a syntax error. It would help of the indenting was fixed because then you would see when an `IF` does not have a matching `END IF` and that the `EXCEPTION` does not match up with the `BEGIN`.

If you want to see where the errors are then compile the package or package body and then immediately afterwards run:

```sql
SHOW ERRORS
```

Alternatively, query the data dictionary:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   user_errors
WHERE  name = 'NMGC_CAABTRN_DB';
```